# Compare variables

Tags: bash, compare

I have a date in file called `lastbackup` with date in the `yyyymmdd` format. Now, I would like to compare this string with current date in the same format in BASH.

I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
LASTBACKUP=sudo cat ./lastbackup

echo $LASTBACKUP
echo $DATE


if [ "$LASTBACKUP" == "$DATE" ]; then
  echo "Do nothing, already processed."
else 
  echo "Do something, not processed"
  echo -n $DATE > ./lastbackup
fi
```

I keep getting `Do something...` and I can't figure out why `DATE` and `LASTBACKUP` variables are different, because in output it looks like they are equal:

```
$ testeq 
20140407
20140407
Do something, not processed
```

When I use (as suggested by Alex):

```
echo "LASTBACKUP: '$LASTBACKUP'"
echo "DATE: '$DATE'"
```

Then I get:

```
$ testeq 
20140407LASTBACKUP: ''
DATE: '20140407'
```

And now it is clear to me what is going on.

Comment: `LASTBACKUP=sudo cat ./lastbackup` is wrong.  Use command substitution.

Comment: `LASTBACKUP=$(sudo cat ./lastbackup)`

Comment: `LASTBACKUP=$(< ./lastbackup)` should work (assuming that you can read the file since you are writing to it anyway).

Comment: If you posted the output of the lines `echo $LASTBACKUP` and `echo $DATE` it should be obious...

Comment: @Axel I don't get it. On the screen it looks like they are equal.

Comment: @TomasGreif what happens when you change `echo $LASTBACKUP` to `echo "LASTBACKUP: '$LASTBACKUP'"` (and dothe same for `$DATE`)?

Comment: @TomasGreif Wooooot? **:-D**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, the problem is probably that you're not actually initializing the `LASTBACKUP` variable anywhere.

But the fact that you're trying to read it with `sudo` bothers me. Doesn't the user that runs the script has permission to read a file that is in its `$HOME`? You are `cd`'ing into `~`, which is the user's home, but since you're sudoing its read makes me think that maybe that file is in `/root/lastbackup`? Why would you `sudo` its reading otherwise?

This should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

# For testings:
# date +%Y%m%d > $HOME/lastbackup # Uncomment to create a "./lastbackup" test file.

# Let's beging

cd ~

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
LASTBACKUP=`cat ./lastbackup`

echo $LASTBACKUP
echo $DATE


if [ "$LASTBACKUP" == "$DATE" ]; then
  echo "Do nothing, already processed."
else 
  echo "Do something, not processed"
  echo -n $DATE > ./lastbackup
fi
```

Another option, if you're running a fairly new version of bash, and since your date format doesn't have any non-number character as separator (no `-` , `/` ...) would be consider the values numbers in the `if`:

```
if (( $LASTBACKUP == $DATE )); then
  echo "Do nothing, already processed."
else 
  echo "Do something, not processed"
  echo -n $DATE > ./lastbackup
fi
```

And, while testing, don't escape the `LASTBACKUP` or `DATE` variables with quotation marks `"`. If there was a problem reading the file (or getting the current `date`, but I doubt that one) you'll see an error. It'll help debugging.

Comment: I am also surprised, but without `sudo` I get permission denied even I  am the owner of both files (script and `lastbackup`) and I am running the script from command line just by entering `bash testeq`

Comment: add a `pwd` right before ` LASTBACKUP=`cat ./lastbackup` ` Make sure you're in the right directory where the `lastbackup` file is.

Comment: Good answer, but I can't agree with the last paragraph.

Comment: @glennjackman why not? I say while testing...

Comment: because quoted and unquoted variable behave differently. You don't want to test your program with unquoted variables, then throw some quotes in at the last second and expect the program to work the same way.

Comment: Sure... if `LASTBACKUP` is not initialized and you try to compare `if [ $LASTBACKUP == $DATE ]` without quotes, he'll see an error in the `if`, which won't occur if the variable is quoted but empty. That's the idea.

Comment: Probably a better test strategy would be to use `set -u`

Comment: @glennjackman, I'm interested in your approach. Wouldn't the variable `LASTBACKUP` be initialized anyway after the line `LASTBACKUP=$(cat ./lastbackup)` ? (Meaning: the variable is actually set, but empty)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the reason this is wrong:

```
LASTBACKUP=sudo cat ./lastbackup
```

When you execute a command in this form:

```
var=val var2=val2 ... command arg arg ...
```

The variables are put into the environment of the command, and *only* into that environment. So, while `cat` is running, it has an environment variable named LASTBACKUP with the value "sudo". Once `cat` is finished, that variable will disappear.

The contents of the ./lastbackup file get `cat`'ed to stdout. I'm surprised you don't see a blank line when you `echo $LASTBACKUP`. Check your files for CRLF line endings, or perhaps the ./lastbackup file does not end with a newline.

When you're debugging and printing variables out, do something more obvious to see their value:

```
printf "LASTBACKUP='%s'\n" "$LASTBACKUP"
# or
for var in DATE LASTBACKUP; do
    printf "%s='%s'\n" "$var" "${!var}"
done
```

bash has a builtin way to read a file so you don't have to call `cat`: this will have you a couple of milliseconds:

```
lastbackup=$(< ./lastbackup)
```

Get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARS -- one day you'll use `PATH=something` and then wonder why your script stops working.

Comment: You are correct, there is no newline in `./lastbackup`.